# Convert grill recipe to broiler and/or oven

Tags: grilling, pizza, oven, broiling

I have a [recipe](http://www.thecookingphotographer.com/2009/05/purple-pizza-with-asparagus-fontina.html) that requires a grill. Its for pizza and specifically I am supposed to:

> Set the pizza on the grill and close
>   the lid. Turn grill to medium high and
>   cook for 5 to 8 minutes or until
>   cooked through. Turn to medium for a
>   thicker crust pizza and cook longer.
>   Remove onto a cookie sheet with tongs.

I don't have a grill so I was wondering if someone knows how to convert this into a recipe for the oven and/or broiler. [This question](http://portablehibachigrill.net/i-found-a-recipe-for-grilling-but-want-to-convert-it-or-the-oven/) on the Portable Hibachi Grill site mentions another recipe and someone says to use the same directions (temperature and time) for the broiler. Is this right and if so what temperature should I set the broiler to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that it's going to work with a broiler, as you'll likely brown the top too much.  You might be able to get away with your oven as hot as it'll go and a pre-heated pizza stone.

As for broiler temperature -- I don't think I've ever set mine to anything less than all the way up when using it.  (but then again, I have an electric oven)

Comment: I posted this assuming that the poster was American, or at least used the same sense of grill vs. broil as Americans, where heat in grilling comes from the bottom, and broiling comes from the top.

Answer (score 1):

Take a large cast iron skillet, place on a burner, and turn to high.

Prepare your pizza, slide to a peel, turn on the broiler, and wait until the skillet starts to smoke.

Quickly shloop the pizza into the skillet, and shove the skillet under the broiler.

Put the handle to the right, wait 5-7 minutes, open the oven, turn 180*, another 5 minutes, and you have delicious stone-style pizza.

Enjoy.